# How do i build shopping app in android studio with games in Unity?

Tags: android

what are the best tools to create a shopping app which also has games like the "Kiddopia" app? Can i build the main app in Android studio and games in Unity and finally produce a seamless single app for the user?
What would be the best way to do this

I have knowledge of android studio programming but starting to learn Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The first choice you will make will be native or cross.

These preferences vary depending on many factors. For example; economic reasons. It will be easier to do it with Unity. Because it is a good game engine.

But if you are aiming for Android Native development. I recommend using [Android Game Dev](https://developer.android.com/games?hl=en)